# Creating a translucent acrylic-like Shader

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders, volumetrics, glass

I am trying to make this model and as you can see in the reference, it looks translucent with a glow on the outer ring, like a solid block of acrylic with thickness. Also, as you can see, it emits light from inside so I have made a wire on the inside with emission.
I have tried making the material with some volumetrics and shaders (glass, transparent, glossy) but it doesn't look believable. Additionaly, it's generating too much of noise. Also, as you can see in the reference, the surface is very rough with some scratches. So any help would be appreciated since I am not that good with nodes. Thanks.

[image: Arc Reactor]

Reference:
[image: References]

(P.S. - I am using 2.79b due to some hardware constrains).

Answer (score 3):

Just use a glass-shader in combination with a volume absorption-shader. The color is emitted by the light.

[image: Rendering]
[image: NodeSetup]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I want it to look a bit plastic-acrylic type and yours looks like glass block with roughness. Any ideas on that?